# How can I monitor the number of incoming and processed files in a directory with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have this PowerShell script that monitors the number of files present in a directory. Here it is:

```
#sleep in seconds
$SleepTimeOut = 300

#start looping here
Do{
     $path = 'TargetDirectory'
     $stats = 0 
     $files = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.ZIP') 
     if ($files -ne $null) {  
          $stats = $files.Count 
          } else { 
     $msg = 'Message: No files'
     Write-Output $msg
     } 
     Get-Date | Out-File -Append 'C:\Monitoring\Logs.csv'
     Write-Output "Count: $stats files" | Out-File -Append 'C:\Monitoring\Logs.csv'

     Write-Output ".. Files COUNT in Progress...Please Don't Close ..`n"
     sleep $SleepTimeOut

}
while ($Exit -ne $True)
```

It appends the results to a CSV file. I just want to know if there is a way to monitor the incoming and processed files within that 5-minute sleep duration of the script. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You could use `IO.FileSystemWatcher` with `Register-ObjectEvent`

Comment: just output the `$files`?

Comment: File listing and quantity check are what I needed. Will definitely try this. Thanks! I'll get back next week since I'm out of the office. :)

Answer (score 0):

As BenH mentioned you can try using events with `IO.FileSystemWather`. If that option does not work for you the other option you have is to use `GetChildItem` for the folder you want to watch and check for the LastWriteTime in each file. Do a comparison check from the last time your loop ran and document any new or updated files.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely give this a try and provide you feedback.